# Error trying to add header for UICollectionView Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm having trouble trying to add a header to my collection view. This is the related part of the code:

```
collectionView?.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.header)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 262.5)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if member == nil {
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let profileHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.header, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeaderView
        if indexPath.section == Section.header {
            profileHeaderView.config(...)
            return profileHeaderView
        } else {

            let reusabelView = UICollectionReusableView()
            let seperatorLine = UIView.seperatorLine()

            reusabelView.addSubview(seperatorLine)
            seperatorLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusabelView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            seperatorLine.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusabelView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            seperatorLine.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusabelView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

            reusabelView.backgroundColor = Color.white
            return reusabelView
        }
    default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

And ProfileHeaderView is subclass of UICollectionReusableView. After running this code and trying to see how it looks like, I get this error:

> the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (>)
>   (null)

Comment: `collectionView?.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.header)` **Where** did you write this code?

Comment: in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your conditions.

Message your receive telling that you do not dequeue your supplementary view from collectionView. So problem lying in parts where your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` returns created (inited) views.

**All views in your collection view must be dequeued from it**. You can read more in  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).